# Prettify JSON before storing to TXT

Tags: c#, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to figure out how to prettify when the JavaScriptSerializer serializes my custom object to json.

string json = _jsonSerializer.Serialize(listToSerializeToJson);

it is just one long string right now, not formatted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an option for that on the built-in [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. However, if you're using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) you can do this.

```
string json=JsonConvert.Serialize(listToSerializeToJson, Formatting.Indented);
```

According to Json.Net's project page, `JavaScriptSerializer` and `DataContractJsonSerializer` do not support creating indented prettified JSON strings.

Comment: By "do not support" I hope you only mean for output.  Presumably they can at least *read* prettified strings.  Else they would not be a JSON implementation.

Comment: I thought that was obvious, given that the question is about how to serialize, not how to deserialize. I will update my answer for those that don't feel like thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for testing/human readability, I like using Json Lint: http://jsonlint.com/.